# Uncatchable Exception when using Future.timeout()

Tags: dart, exception, future

I came across a constellation with Futures where apparently it's not possible to catch an thrown exception. In the following minimal reproducable example, assume we can only change code in main, all functions starting with underscore are inside a packages code:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    var resultFuture = _complexAsyncTask();
    var timeoutFuture = resultFuture.timeout(const Duration(seconds: 1), onTimeout: () {
      print("timeout");
      return "timeout return";
    });

    final String result = await timeoutFuture;

    print(result);
  } catch (e) {
    print("catched exception: $e");
  }
}

Future<String> _complexAsyncTask() => _withTryFinallyAwait(() => _innerComplexAsyncTask());

Future<T> _withTryFinallyAwait<T>(Future<T> Function() fn) async {
  try {
    return await fn();
  } finally {
    //do something in finally
  }
}

Future<String> _innerComplexAsyncTask() async {
  return await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    throw Exception('exception thrown after 2 seconds delay');
  });
}
```

I have tried adding .catchError and .onError to the Futures i create in main, but to no avail. No matter what i tried, the exception thrown inside _innerComplexAsyncTask() is uncatchable.

If we remove the timeout and instead await the resultFuture, the exception is indeed caught by the try-catch block in main. But seemingly no chance when a timeout is shorter than the time needed by async code to throw an exception.

How can we catch the exception in the example above ?

Comment: I just see ""timeout" and "timeout return" printed when I run this in dartpad.dev or with the `dart run` command. How are you running this, and with which version of the Dart SDK?

Comment: @Irn Dart SDK version: 3.0.3 (stable) (Wed May 31 15:35:05 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64". I'm running the example code in a fresh flutter project in vs code, with debugger attached. The original constellation is inside the [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for flutter

Comment: @Irn upon further testing i think this is related to the dart / flutter debugger. When i run the code with dart run / flutter run then i have the same result as you do: no uncatched exception. However, with the exact same code when i press F5 in vs code to "Start Debugging" then i have the uncatched exception.